# crypto.getCurves is undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, oauth, cryptography

I am trying to use an oauth helper library called 'openid-client'. I am getting an error that reads in part '`(TypeError): getCurves is not a function`'. I poke around and find that getCurves is part of an inbuilt module of node.js 'crypto'.

If I `console.log(typeOf(crypto.getCurves))` I get `undefined`. If I `console.log(crypto)` I see that crypto has many available methods but getCurves is not among them.

I am running node on my macbook and my project is a barebones npx create-react-app app with openid-client installed.

The node documentation outlines a way for determining if crypto support is unavailable, but that does not seem to indicate that crypto is unavailable for me.

I'm not sure why my version of node crypto does not have getCurves.  Is there a way to install the correct version? Is there some sort of encryption restriction I am hitting due to OS? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`node-openid-client` is using APIs which are provided by Node and are missing in browser.

Node is being used by CRA as a development tool. App itself is running in browser and can't access Node's API-s, so it doesn't matter which Node version CRA is using.

When built, app is a set of JS files which can be served by a webserver (such as Nginx) directly without using Node at all.

So, this library can't be used with CRA apps.

https://github.com/panva/node-openid-client/issues/218

Answer (score 0):

As you said, `crypto` is a built-in module, which means that its functionality depends on the version of node.js you have installed (you can check it via `node -v` from the shell or via `console.log(process.version)` at runtime).

Node.js [API docs](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_getcurves) say that `getCurves()` was added in v2.3.0, so make sure your node is more recent than that.

Comment: Thank you. ```node -v``` shows that I have node v13.6.0